# Error : Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, html, node-oracledb

I've trying to import oracledb and in my website the warnig is that expected a JAVASCRIPT module but the server responded with a MIME. I've trying to push the "resultado" of the HTML function into my js, but this is happening.I'm trying to use ES6 import and export, a browserify, watchify and nothing is solving that.

```js
import * as oracledb from '../node_modules/@types/oracledb'

async function getConexao() {
    try {
        const conexao = await oracledb.getConnection({ user: "SYSTEM", password: "ospiri", connectionString: "localhost/xe" });
        global.conexao = conexao;
        return conexao;
    }catch(erro){
        return null;
    }
}

async function estrutureSe() {
    const conexao = await getConexao();
    if (conexao==undefined) return null;
    const sql = `create table bilhetes (
        cod_bilhete number(20),
        data_geracao date,
        hora_geracao timestamp,
        primary key (cod_bilhete))`;
    try {
        await conexao.execute(sql);
        return true;
    }catch(erro){
        return false;
    }
}

export {getConexao, estrutureSe};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="sistema de bilhete de tranporte publico">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js" integrity="sha512-BNaRQnYJYiPSqHHDb58B0yaPfCu+Wgds8Gp/gU33kqBtgNS4tSPHuGibyoeqMV/TJlSKda6FXzoEyYGjTe+vXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <title>Ospiri - Serviços de transporte</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class ="header">
        <nav class ="header-menu"> 
            <a class="header-menu-item">Ospiri</a>
            <div class ="botao-pginicial">
                <a class ="pg-inicial" href ="../index.html">Página inicial</a>
            </div>
            <div class ="botao-recarga">
                <a class ="recarga" href = "recarga.html">Recarga</a>
            </div>
            <div class ="botao-verificar">
                <a class ="verificar" href = "verificar.html">Verificar bilhete</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class= "content">
        <section class ="main-content">
            
            <div class = "main-content-label"> 
                <script id="codbilhete">
                 var bilhetes = []
                        function sorteio() { // gerando um valor aleatório do bilhete 
                             return Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
                        }
                        while(bilhetes.length < 1) {
                         var resultado = sorteio();
                            if(bilhetes.indexOf(resultado) === -1){
                           bilhetes.push(resultado);
                          }
                          document.write("Seu código é :" + resultado)
                        }
             </script>
             <form>
                <input type="number" name = "bilhete"><br><small>Digite seu código para registrá-lo!</small><br>
                <button onclick="add()">Registrar</button>
            </form>
            <script type="module" src="../index.js"></script>
            </div>
            
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
        <nav class ="footer-menu"> 
            <div class ="botao-pginicial">
                <a class ="pg-inicial">Página inicial</a>
            </div>
            <div class ="botao-recarga">
                <a class ="recarga">Recarga</a>
            </div>
            <div class ="botao-verificar">
                <a class ="verificar">Verificar bilhete</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

      </footer>

</body>
</html>
```